# Can I hide an image button on a layout, (dimensions and background) until a call to set visible?

Tags: android, layout, imagebutton, dimensions, visible

I have a hidden image button in one of my xmls layouts, with a background set to a drawable image.  I set the visibility to invisible, as I only want the image to display every once in a while.  The problem is, even if the drawable isn't shown, the image button still takes us space - Is there a way to hide the background image, and make it's dimensions 0 until I call on it to be shown in my main class?

Thanks!

Edit:  So in my xml, how would I write that?

```
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/myimage" android:visibility="invisible" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_gravity="center" android:background="@drawable/my_image"></ImageButton>
```

I want to have the image always gone, unless a certain condition occurs, I then want the image to be visible under that one condition.  So in my xml I would need to be set to GONE, but in my conditional statement so I say something like:

myimage.setVisibility(SHOW);?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All views, including ImageButton, inherit from android.view.View, so they all have a visibility attribute that can be set. Instead of setting the visibility of the drawable resource, set it on the ImageButton.

Comment: It is set the the image button itself, but more some reason it keeps the dimensions of the drawable while not displaying it (if that makes sense).

Comment: Indeed, I saw the suggestion to set to "GONE" and voted it up. That seems the best solution.

Comment: What If I am changing Visibility to Gone in my xml and call for it to be shown under a certain condition in my method, I edited in my extra question.  Thanks!

Comment: All XML attributes have an associated java method. In this case you'd call setVisibility.

Comment: I am overconfusing myself I believe:  Would those be my_image.setVisibility(View.GONE); at the beggining of my method and then my_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) in my conditional?

Comment: It's really your choice. Android provides developers with the tools to do both declarative design and procedural design, so you can do it in code, in XML, or some mix between the two. In this case, it probably makes the most sense to set the initial value in XML and programmatically change it when appropriate.

Answer (score 14):

Try setting the visibility to `GONE`

Comment: What If I am changing Visibility to Gone in my xml and call for it to be shown under a certain condition in my method, I edited in my extra question.  Thanks!

Comment: Nice one! I'm doing a ProgressBar at the center of screen and switch to ImageView if the photo finishes loading. I just use VISIBLE and GONE. Your solution works.

Answer (score 9):

Don't set the width/height to zero, that's ugly. The view will always take up the space, unless you change the visibility setting. This is the code you want:

myImageButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

View.GONE - invisible, takes up no space
View.INVISIBLE - invisible, but still takes up space
View.VISIBLE - use this to bring it back

Comment: What If I am changing Visibility to Gone in my xml and call for it to be shown under a certain condition in my method, I edited in my extra question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Set Visibility property of Imageview like this in java

```
imgView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
imgView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
imgView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Or like this in XML

```
android:visibility="visible"
android:visibility="gone"
android:visibility="invisible"
```

Result for each will be like this

[image]