# Want a button to not appear in Android if a file size is over 1 KB

Tags: android, button

I want to first check to see if a file is over 1 KB. If it is I want the button to be visible. If not I do not want it to be visible. Checking the files  size is easy and I can check this condition using an if statement. I just do not know how to make the button visible and invisible.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Can I hide an image button on a layout, (dimensions and background) until a call to set visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249237/can-i-hide-an-image-button-on-a-layout-dimensions-and-background-until-a-call)

myImageButton.setVisibility(View.Gone);

myImageButton.setVisibility(View.Visible);

myImageButton.setVisibility(View.Invisible);

Comment: Thanks. I probably should have searched here instead of Google.

Comment: It's np, and yeah sometimes searching here does provide better results for technical questions (at least you see them higher up in the results list).